# Automatic File Move

Tags: php, move

I need to move some files from one folder to other two, and then delete the file thats in the Source folder.

I've made this code, but it's not working.

```
<?php
$sDirectory     = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Signature\xDoc-MX\Stores\areas\Adidas\instances\01\errTXT';
$sNewDirectory  = '\\10.55.33.34\D$\commun\General\ventas\Coppel\Originales';
$sNewDirectory2 = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Signature\xDoc-MX\Stores\areas\Adidas\instances\01\errTXT\Coppel';
$Word="rfc        = COP-920428Q20";
if( !is_dir( $sNewDirectory ) )
 {
    mkdir( $sNewDirectory, 0777, TRUE );
}
if( !is_dir( $sNewDirectory2 ) )
{
    mkdir( $sNewDirectory2, 0777, TRUE );
}
$sFilter = '12';
if( is_dir( $sDirectory ) ) 
{
    $rDir = opendir( $sDirectory );
    while( ( $sFile = readdir( $rDir ) ) !== FALSE ) 
    {
        if( ( $sFile == '.' ) || ( $sFile === '..' ) )
        {
            continue;
        }
        $sFilePath = $sDirectory . '/' . $sFile;
        $sContents = file_get_contents( $sFilePath );
        $Line = $sContents;
    if (preg_match($Word,$Line)){
        if( strpos( $sContents, $sFilter ) !== FALSE )
        {
            $sNewFileName  = $sNewDirectory . '/' . $sFile;
            $sNewFileName2 = $sNewDirectory2 . '/' . $sFile;
           if( !copy( $sFilePath, $sNewFileName ) || !copy( $sFilePath, $sNewFileName2 ) )
            {
                echo 'Could not move: ' . $sFile;
            }
            else
            {
                unlink( $sFilePath );
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Any Idea why is not working?

Regards,
Alan.

Comment: do you get any errors?

Comment: You could always use `exec("move /path/to/directory /path/to/destination");`. That would move the entire directory and delete the previous directory (because you are moving it not copying it). I'm assuming the script is on Windows because of the file paths. If using unix just replace `move` with `mv`

Comment: @iam-decoder Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash

Comment: @honerlawd I tried it, but I need to move just specific files that contain the "word"

Comment: To fix that error change `$Word="rfc        = COP-920428Q20";` to `$Word="/rfc        = COP-920428Q20/";`. Your original string is not a regular expression.

Comment: I've modified it and it no longers shows me that error, but it still doen't move any file, despite many files that fulfill the requirement.

Comment: in the files are you using a tab character or spaces?

Comment: actually nevermind, just use this: `$Word= "/rfc[\t\s]*?=[\t\s]*?COP-920428Q20/";`